# Hide Scala generated case class methods in the IntelliJ UML Diagram?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I have defined a case class `SimpleChangeLog` like so:

```scala
case class SimpleChangeLog(
  createdAt: Instant,
  createdBy: Member,
  updatedAt: Instant,
  updatedBy: Member,
)
```

Since it is a case class, Scala generates additional methods like `apply` and `tupled` behind the scenes automatically. This is great, because I don't have to *see* them and instead I can focus on the actual domain that `SimpleChangeLog` describes!

The only issue is when I want to visualize this using IntelliJ's UML Diagrams:

[image: UML diagram of SimpleChangeLog showing all the hidden case class methods in plain view]

Suddenly all of those automatically generated "hidden" methods are in plain view and not in a good way. They pollute the diagram with noise that is irrelevant to the actual `SimpleChangeLog` model.

How can I get IntelliJ's UML diagram to show *my case class properties* like `createdBy` but hide the automatically generated ones like `tupled`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am fairly certain that **this feature is not available** as of IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.1, built May 10, 2022

The only workaround I am aware of – which no doubt is impossible in most cases – is to use `trait` or `class` in place of a `case class`.

There is [a ticket open on the IntelliJ Scala Plugin](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-20220/Ability-to-filter-out-automatically-generated-methods-of-case-cl) for adding this functionality.

If you too would like to see this feature added to IntelliJ, you can vote on that ticket.